# map one to one with multiple primary key columns entity framework code first

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, code-first

I have 2 tables with 2 primary key columns. Their structure is:

```
public class X
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int line {get;set;}
}

public class Y
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int line {get;set;}
}
```

They are related with one to one relationship.

How can I map the 2 tables in entity framework code first to reflect their relation?

Table Y is optional but Table X is required.

Comment: I always wonder what the point of having one to one table relationships is.  If the relationship is one to one, why not have a single table/class?

Comment: @BenRobinson I always wonder that at first but it may have connected on the security issues. There are some users that are not allowed or have no enough privilege to see some detail on the other table that's why they split it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood right, maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
public class X
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Y"), Column(Order=0)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Key, ForeignKey("Y"), Column(Order=1)]
    public int line { get; set; }

    public virtual Y Y { get; set; }
}

public class Y
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order=1)]
    public int line { get; set; }

    public virtual X X { get; set; }
}
```

With the `Key` attribute you are saying EF that those properties would be the keys of your table. Adding the `ForeignKey` attribute, provides info to EF telling it which navigation property represents the relationship it is a foreign key for. Finally, the `Column` attribute is telling EF which property of `X` should match which one on `Y`. If I misunderstood your problem please let me know so I can change my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class X
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int line {get; set;}

    public virtual Y Y { get; set; }
}

public class Y
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int line {get; set;}

    public virtual X X { get; set; }
}
```

and add a configuration,

```
modelBuilder.Entity<X>()
            .HasOptional<Y>(u => u.ID)
            .WithOptionalDependent(c => c.ID)
            .Map(p => p.MapKey("ID"));
```

Comment: The tables are related with 2 primary keys. How do I configure both? In youe example you use only the Id Key column.